# ASCII Art gets bugged 1 out of 10-15 times when I open my batch file

Tags: batch-file, cmd, ascii-art, windows-terminal

I am working on a batch file that has ASCII art as a welcome page.

The ASCII art gets [echoed weirdly](https://i.postimg.cc/C1Lfs7QF/Windows-Terminal-qvl-Am-FCe8o.png) sometimes. It is missing some of the bottom lines. It is supposed to look like [this](https://i.postimg.cc/gk6LsnN6/Windows-Terminal-zal-Mun-GSYu.png).

I tried changing the window height and width of cmd.exe/terminal.exe as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14842910/21355835). I tested it with `mode cols=135 lines=38` (with that the ASCII art has 1 empty line above and 1 empty line beneath it) and `mode con: cols=135 lines=60` where as with `lines=60` the "bug" seems to occur less frequently (around 1 in 30-35 times). I changed the terminal.exe's window height and width via it's Settings tab to the same values. Increasing the value for the window's height seems to make the "bug" occur less frequently.

I also tried using `type "ASCII.txt"` which made the "bug" more apparent (more lines missing).

But I want to keep the cmd.exe/terminal.exe window small. Is there a way to have my ASCII art displayed without any occurring bugs with `mode con: cols=135 lines=38` and without having to make my ASCII art smaller?

This is my code for reference:

```
@echo off
title fantazia.pw
mode con: cols=135 lines=38

for /f "delims=: tokens=*" %%g in ('findstr /b ::: "%~f0"') do @echo(%%g

:::
:::                               .:-=======--:.
:::                        .-=*%@@%%#**++++**#%@@@#+=:
:::                    .-*@@%*=:.                .-+#%@%*-.
:::                 .=#@%+-                           .-+%@#=.
:::               -#@%+.                                  .=%@#-
:::             -%@*:                                        :*@%=
:::           :%@*.     ....                          ....     .*@%:
:::          +@%:  :+*++=--=+++*+=-:.        .:-=+*+++==-=++*+-  :%@*
:::        .%@+ .+*-           :@-:-=++++++++=-:-@-           -**. +@%.
:::       .@@- +#.              %-              :@              .** :@@:
:::      .@@- #=    .+%*=-      %*              +%      -=*%*:    =# :@@.
:::      #@+ *+    -@@+    :=++#%@*=-.      .:=*@%#+++:    =@@=    =# =@#
:::     :@@ :%  +: *@@@+=+*-.      .:-++++++-:.      .-*+=+%@@# .+  %- %@-
:::     +@* ++ *%  :@#-..:     -*##*=+%#==##*-*##*=     ::.-#@-  #* =* +@*
:::     *@= #= +@%+#%         %*++@@@@@----@@@@@*+*%.        #%+%@* -% -@#
:::     *@+ #-  =%@@@:       --  -@+##+-. -+##+@-  :=       .%@@%=  :% =@*
:::     -@% %:     .:*#-       *@@@ -=-*++#-=- @@@*.      -#*-.     .@ #@=
:::      @@:@.        =*      *@@#%%.  .##:  .#%#@@#      ++         @:@@
:::      +@@#        .%%:     *@:             .  .@#     :%%.        #@@*
:::      .@@*      -#@@@@@@%*=:++.              .+*:=*%@@@@@@#=      +@@:
:::    .=%@@#    .%@@@@@@%%@@@@%=. *@@%:  .#@@* .=%@@@@%%@@@@@@%.    *@@%+.
:::  .#@%=:-@:   +@@@@=.     -+@@%:=%@@@  %@@%=:%@@*-.    .=@@@@*   .@-:=#@#.
::: .@@=    =#   +@@@:  ==-=-++.=@@: :*+  +*- .@@+.=+-==-=  .@@@*   *+    -@@.
::: +@*      %-   %@@: :=-@@% %@+-@%          #@==@@ %@@=-- .@@@.  :@      +@*
::: *@+      :%    #@%. =:=+- -:+:@@          %@.*:- :++:= .%@#.   #-      =@#
::: -@%       #= +- -@@+.:+#@=-::=@-          :@=::-=@%+- =@@= :+ -#       #@=
:::  #@+      .%. +%@@%**#+==+++*+.             =*+++==+#**%@@%+ .%:      =@%
:::   #@*      :%:       %@+..        .::::.        ..=@#       :%-      +@%.
:::    +@%=      **:  :=**-        :#@#*++*#@#-        -**=:. .**.     -%@*
:::     .*@@*-.   -@%=.           -@==+*##**=-@-.          .=#@=   .-*@@*.
:::        -+#%@@@%#+%@#=.       :--::::::::::--:       .=#@%+*%@@@@#+-
:::                   .+%@#+:.                      .:=#@%+.
:::                      .=*%@@@%%##**********##%%@@@%#=:
:::                            .::---========---::.
:::
<nul set /p "=press any key to continue..."
pause >nul
exit
```

Comment: [May be related](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76113529/windows-11-bat-file-some-output-missing-or-on-wrong-line-in-the-cmd-window) (I saw it once but didn't care, as it worked fine next time. That makes at least four people who experienced this. Seems to be a relatively new bug. If we're lucky, it gets solved in one of the next Windows updates)

Comment: This seems to be it because the bug occurs so random and I noticed that some output of `findstr` was not showing in console even though it should've before. Thanks for the hint! I really hope that bug gets fixed in the near future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might be seeing a combination of:

- https://github.com/microsoft/terminal/issues/5094
- https://github.com/microsoft/terminal/issues/14512 (I know this one mentions Visual Studio, but I think it applies to any process that writes to the console too quickly on startup)

The Windows Terminal currently doesn't support a commandline application resizing the dimensions of the viewport. That includes trying to set the window size with `mode`

If it's the second thing (which I'm more confident about), then I *think* that should be fixed in [Terminal 1.18](https://github.com/microsoft/terminal/releases/tag/v1.18.1462.0)